# Is the distribution of the logarithm of the mean of Bernoulli random variables ($\log \overline X$) still asymptotically normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

Let $\overline X$ be the mean of a Bernoulli random variable (r.v.)

$$\overline X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$$

where $X_i \in \{0, 1\}$. So based on Central Limit Theoreom,

$$\overline X \sim \mathcal{N}\Big(p, \frac{p(1-p)}{n}\Big)$$

Obviously, $0 < \overline X < 1$ (let's ignore the boundary 0 and 1 edgecase for now).

I am interested in knowing if another r.v. $\log \overline X$ is asymptotically normal.

At first, I thought for $\log \overline X$ to be normal, then $\overline X$ should be log-normal, which isn't the case as described above.

However, I did some computer simulation, it seems to be the case that $\log \overline X$ is still normal, how to show it formally, please?

[image]

Comment: you could have a look at continuous mapping theorem and delta rule.

Comment: @JesperHybel Could you please be more specific about how to use delta rule?

Comment: The non-zero probability of $\bar{X}=0$ (so taking $\log(0) $) is your main problem; this non-zero probability occurs at every finite sample size so you can't really argue for  a sequence of random variables that converge to something. If you deal with this in some way (there are a couple of possible things you might do) then you could skirt this issue.

Comment: @Glen_b, could you please suggest more details about "the couple of possible things"?

Comment: e.g. One potential approach is to condition on being >0 and then construct a sequence of random variables from there.Presumably your simulation analysis would have excluded cases with $\bar{X}=0$ had you observed any.

Comment: I see. In my simulation, $p = 0.3$, and $n= 100,000$, so it's very unlikely to have $\bar X$. It may be more of a theoretical issue.

Comment: @Martijn Weterings, what do you mean by degenerate in this case, please?

Comment: See, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look here [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)

So $\bar X_n$ is asymptotically normal with mean $\mu=p$ and variance $\sigma^2=p(1-p)$ in the sense that

$$ \sqrt n(\bar X_n - \mu ) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$$

this is sometimes written as

$$\bar X_n \stackrel{a}{\sim} \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$$

so here $\sigma^2/n = p(1-p)/n = Var\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i \right)$

Then with delta method which is based on among other thing the continuous mapping theorem

$\sqrt n(g(\bar X_n) - g(\mu)) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 g'(\mu)^2)$

where in the current case $g(t) = \log(t)$ and $g'(t) = 1/t$

so variance of $\sqrt n(g(\bar X_n) - g(\mu))$ should be $\sigma^2/\mu^2$ and hence

$\log \bar X_n \stackrel{a}{\sim} \mathcal N(g(\mu),\sigma^2/(n\mu^2))$.

so variance $\log \bar X_n$ is $\sigma^2/(n\mu^2)$

Comment: Don't you mean "so variance should be $\sigma^2/(n\mu^2)$"

Comment: have edited to make more clear which varince I'm referring to when. But yes the variance you are interested in is $Var(\log \bar X_n) ) = \sigma^2/(n \mu^2)$.